# С недавних пор гит перестал отправлять комиты на сервер

Tags: git

Иницилизурую гит в папке проекта. `git init`. Создаю репозиторий на гитхабе. Делаю публичным. Копирую https.
В папке проекта прописываю

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/Akk/project.git
```

Далее `git add .`
Далее `git commit -m "Скидывай мои файлы!!!!!! ##@##зь"`
Далее `git push origin main`
И мне пишет:

```
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Akk/projec.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Чо ему надо от меня я не пойму??? Ещё в октябре всё работало как надо и главной веткой был main.
Сейчас же я заметил что опять сменилось на master, потому между попытками переустановил git на новую версию. Репозиторий на гитхабе тоже естественно снёс вместе с папкой .git. После чего пробовал ещё раз делать всё заного. С репозиторием работаю только я, никем и ничем он не занят, главная ветка там main, сам пустой и никакого клонирования делать не надо.

Comment: А не пробовал сделать то, что там написано?

Comment: pull?................

Comment: ......да.......

Comment: зачем мне pull если репозиторий на серваке абсолютно голый? Там нет ничего.

Comment: А почему люди не хотят попробовать решение, которое ничего не стоит, кроме двух секунд?

Comment: Я пробовал это делать. Ошибка после пула такая же возвращается. Текст ошибки уже не скопирую, но вот после ```git fetch origin```, пишет это: 
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), 1.12 KiB | 1024 bytes/s, done.
From https://github.com/PandaBlum/djangobleat
 * [new branch]      main       -> origin/main

Comment: и ошибка прежняя, ничего не меняется.

Comment: А почему аккаунты разные - Akk и PandaBlum?

Comment: я в примере изменил аккаунт. Потом уже подумал что смысла не имеет. Издержки профессии и параноик, извиняюсь.

Comment: `git fetch` это не тоже самое, что `git pull`, то что после `git fetch` возвращается такая же ошибка при попытке push-а, это нормально и ожидаемо, т.к. изменения из remote репозитория все еще не попали в ваш локальный `main`. Так что все же сделайте `git pull`. Не может у вас после `git pull` возвращаться такая же ошибка.

Comment: А по поводу "репозиторий пустой" - сделайте `git log origin/main` и увидите, что непустой.

Comment: Он был и пустым и не пустым. Я всяко пробовал. Персоздавал пустой репозиторий, создавал не пустой. Ошибка такая же была. Всё запушилось только после того как создал репозиторий с другим именем. Как подключился к нему локально с сделал прежние действия, всё прошло успешно. Не знаю почему так. Однако pull не помогал.